# Bootstrap layout doesn't work with safari

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I made a website where the layout renders perfectly with any browser but Safari... The cols are not aligned I get images out of their divs. I have no idea why this happen. Did you experience such problems ?

Here is an example of the code (using Bootstrap 4):

```
        <div class="row" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6"
            style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <div class="row align-items-center" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                <div
                    class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 text-center"
                    style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"></div>
                <div
                    class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-9 text-center"
                    style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                    <titre2>{{sections[section.sections[0]]['name']}}</titre2>
                </div>
                <div
                    class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 box empty2"
                    style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-9 boxsup"
                    style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                    <a
                        href="{{ path('section', {'section_name': sections[section.sections[0]]['name']}) }}">
                        <center>
                            <img class="ownthumbnail1"
                                src="{{ asset(contents[0]|first) | imagine_filter('medium') }}"
                                alt="">
                        </center>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6"
            style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <div class="row align-items-center" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                <div
                    class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-9 text-center"
                    style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                    <titre2>{{sections[section.sections[1]]['name']}}</titre2>
                </div>
                <div
                    class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 text-center"
                    style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-9 boxsup"
                    style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                    <a
                        href="{{ path('section', {'section_name': sections[section.sections[1]]['name']}) }}">
                        <center>
                            <img class="ownthumbnail2"
                                src="{{ asset(contents[1]|first) | imagine_filter('medium') }}"
                                alt="">
                        </center>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div
                    class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 box empty2"
                    style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example that shows the end content. It's difficult to diagnose concerns like 'images out of their divs' when we can't see the actual images.

Comment: The doc clearly says that windows [safari is not supported](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/browsers-devices/#desktop-browsers)

Comment: @pbenard ... I'm not sure why you're operating on the assumption that this persons issue with Safari is specific to Safari for Windows, which was discontinued by Apple in 2012.

Comment: @RobertC I understand that you cannot be sure of yourself, and as you can see, it's just a comment, not an answer. Have I say that the asker is using windows ? no. But it's interresting to know that this version of bootstrap is not supported by windows safari.

Comment: I confirm, it doesn't work with iOS and Mac Safari

Comment: Please do not hide code behind a link. Instead bring all relevant code into the question so that it is self contained. If the link dies for whatever reason the question becomes useless. Thank you.

Comment: I understand @Bugs. Since I don't know where in the code the mistake is, I'd like to bring everything. I'll then edit my question to point out where the mistake was. The website is available here if you want to take a look: http://www.debzsud.com/

Comment: This behaves the same for me in Chrome and Safari... https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/jwRzwR. Can you actually reproduce the problem for us?

Comment: I'll try, but I wonder if this was not a matter of cache to empty. I can't reproduce the error neither. Just two other people who sent me the screenshots of the messy layout. They used safary 10 on mac

Comment: Bootstrap 4 has a class specifically for handling responsive imagest `.img-fluid` https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/images/#responsive-images

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65234112/7186739

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who is still having this issue, I was able to fix it by adding

```
.row:before, .row:after {
display: flex !important;
}
```

Obviously this isn't the most elegant solution and you may have to look through your code for checks and balances sake, but it should do the trick in the meantime until they fix it.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit ? What issue are you talking about ?

Answer (score 4):

Without a better example of code it's difficult to diagnose the exact problem you claim to be experiencing with Apple Safari and Bootstrap v4.  That being said, it seems that based on the structure provided you could greatly simplify your code which might have the added benefit of addressing your issues.

In case you have issues with SO rendering Bootstrap v4 Alpha you can also view a Bootply of this code: https://www.bootply.com/o8dF8rD9IH

But essentially what is happening here is that we're relying on the `.offset-*-*` feature of the Bootstrap Grid system to avoid the various empty `<div>` elements in your current code.  This greatly simplifies the amount of code necessary to achieve the same results.

Applying `.img-responsive` to the images (and a width to that class) allows the images to better scale depending on the screen resolution.  This should help alleviate situations where the image exceeds the confines of your column.

```css
/* Backgrounds just to illustrate .container shape */
.container-fluid {
  background: #eee;
}

.col-md-4 {
  background: #ddd;
}

/* Make .img-responsive images use 100% of the space */
.img-responsive { 
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 offset-md-2">
   <h1>Title #1</h1>
   <a href="#null"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/" class="img-responsive" /></a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
   <h1>Title #2</h1>
   <a href="#null"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/" class="img-responsive" /></a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tips. I know the code snippet is short, but my entire website looks like shit with safari, and looks good with other browsers. SO to me it was more a general question like "what could be messing around with Safari + Bootstrap 4 ?"

Comment: @Robert_C I edited the question and give a code snippet of my website.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding from your question, First you need to check that have you add image responsive class or not. In bootstrap4 , they change some class name. So you can go through [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/images/). If possible put link of your site so I can give you better answer for that.

You need add class.

> img-thumbnail

**NOTE**

First check your bootstrap version.Sometime you used version bootstrap version 3 and class used bootstrap version 4. That's why they conflict by class.

Comment: check here:  www.debzsud.com

Comment: @debzsud Actually you used bootstrap version 3. And in your code you used bootstrap 4 class. Please change either bootstrap version or bootstrap class.